# How to handle multiple responses from single web service call in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, asynchronous, web-services

> I have a requirement where a web service call should be fired from the flex side and this web service is an async web service which would return more than one response.
>
> > In current Flex environment that I have worked in , when we call a webservice - we get a single response corresponding to that web service, but how take make a webservice call which should keep listening to multiple responses ??

---

Actually the requirement is that when I send a request from the flex side to the server side, the server side should start sending the response data as and when they are processed.  To send the complete response in one go might take several minutes based on the request, so the requirement is that the server should return the data in small chunks so that the UI starts processing and displaying the response.

I was contemplating if we could send a remote object or a web service request to the server side and there on the server starts pushing the data back to the client.....Blaze DS appears to be an option , but
in such a case the server starts broadcasting and the client listens to that broadcast,, so it does not look to be so efficient in my requirement and moreover I doubt if the server will push unique data back to the respective clients in the scenario when there a multiple users sending the requests??

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

I read somewhere that in web service using axis or xsf , a webservice request could return multiple responses,,, In such a case will the flex client listen the response send after the first response?

Comment: Why wouldn't you squeeze multiple responses into one response, just return everything you need in one XML for example...

Comment: Trying to figure the same thing, but can't seem to find an answer anywhere.